# kentico successfull authentication event

Tags: authentication, events, kentico

the case is to update a user field after successful user login to kentico CMS, like updating last login date and time.

The scenario is for one-time phone verification by sending the passcode to the user using custom MFAuthentication module. When a user successfully login to Kentico  UserMFRequired field should be changed to false, I think it should be changed when an event occurred but which event?

Answer (score 4):

I believe you're looking for the Authenticate.Execute global event handler.  Check out the documentation for more information.  https://docs.kentico.com/k10/custom-development/handling-global-events/reference-global-system-events#Reference-Globalsystemevents-SecurityEvents